# how to Fix Display Message in multiple line

Tags: css, angular, html

```css
.abc{
white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<label >student</Label>:<span class="abc">He is a good boy </br> he is also kind'</span>
```

Say I am displaying the message in Angular application in 2 line Like this:
LabelStudent:Ram is a good boy,
he is also kind.

I want the second line message i.e. He is also kind, should be displayed just below the first message and not beneath the label

Comment: This seems more like a CSS question than an Angular question.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I have reproduced a demo over [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wONVRL).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <label>student :</label> 
  <div class="information">
    <span>He is a good boy</span>
    <span> he is also kind'</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

.information {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```